# Connect double-click event of QListView with method in PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I’ve got a PyQt `QListView` object, and I want a method to run when it is double-clicked. This should be trivial, but it doesn't seem to work. My code is as follows:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        lb = QListView()
        self.connect(lb, SIGNAL('doubleClicked()'), self.someMethod)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(lb, 0, 0)
        centralWidget.setLayout(grid)

    def someMethod(self):
        print "It happened!"
```

I’ve tried `clicked()` and `entered()` methods too, but they do not work either. These events are all listed in the [documentation here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemview.html#doubleClicked).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems to work if:

```
self.connect(lb, SIGNAL('doubleClicked()'), self.someMethod)
```

Is replaced with the new syntax of:

```
lb.doubleClicked.connect(self.someMethod)
```

The latter is much more elegant too. I still do not know why the original syntax did not work, however.

Answer (score 3):

It will also work if you use:

```
self.connect(lb,QtCore.SIGNAL("itemDoubleClicked (QListWidgetItem *)"),self.someMethod)
```

check the pyqt reference, then  copy and paste the signal as is.

I know you already solved it. but I think knowing more than one method will be better.

Comment: That doesn’t seem to work for me in pyqt4. I also tried self.connect(lb, SIGNAL('itemSelectionChanged()'), self.someMethod), but that doesn’t work either. It’s annoying, as I now want to use a keypressed signal, which doesn't seem to be available via lb.keyPressed.

Answer (score 1):

`itemDoubleClicked` is a signal emitted by `QListWidget` and not `QListView`. I tested  Moayyad Yaghi's suggestion and it did not work for me at least on Qt 4 with python 2.5

Though, `lb.doubleClicked.connect(self.someMethod)` works perfectly fine.

Comment: Looks like it comes from QAbstractItemView: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#doubleClicked